# Why does Captain Krasnovsky wear a Science Division uniform? [TOS]

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Across the franchise we've seen several Starfleet officers wearing unexpected colors for their rank and position. However usually there's a good explanation for these seeming aberrations - Commodore Oh is the Head of Starfleet Security, so that may explain why she wore an Operations uniform.

But Captain Krasnovsky? According to TOS: "Court Martial", he's a *starship captain*... and yet he dresses like a science officer. Even starship captains Janeway and Crusher, both former science officers, were put into Command Division.

[image]

Outside of Krasnovsky I don't think we've ever seen a starship captain who wore anything else other than Command colors. What might make Krasnovsky so special?

Comment: Nobody on the production design team was paying rigorous attention to these color schemes at the time.  So if this has an answer, it's just going to be based on somebody inserting a post-facto justification of this particular "mistake" into some later work.

Comment: LtCdr. Jadzia Dax continued wearing her Science Division uniform while being in command of the USS Defiant, and Abramsverse Cdr. Spock wore his Science uniform while commanding the USS Enterprise, but those were particular circumstances. Memory Alpha notes the script originally had Krasnovsky's character as a "Star Command Captain" and not a starship captain, so someone probably just didn't bother changing it.

Comment: @Buzz Oh I'm aware. And frankly a fan's reinterpretation is sort of what I was hoping for anyway. But any Beta Canon material touching the subject sounds interesting!

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 I do recall Dax taking command in her Science uniform, though I do believe a case could be made that Sisko was still the official CO. To me it seems like any other instance when the captain leaves the bridge and puts another officer in charge for a little while. That's interesting about Memory Alpha's notes! I wonder what "Star Command" is even supposed to mean? Terminology was pretty weird back in those days.

Comment: @rr_cola Which is why I said "particular circumstances" re: Dax and Spock, yeah. As for Star Command, either that's what they called the overall Starfleet Command at the time or Buzz Lightyear is secretly canon to Star Trek!

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Ah, the two logical alternatives. My vote definitely has to be Buzz Lightyear :P

Comment: To boldly go to infinity and beyond!